# How to use multiple autofocus attribute in different forms of same component in Angular on ionic elements?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

Here Autofocus is works only for Login page not working for Signup page.Also i want to fix autofocus on anther screens of same component And all bellow code is present in a single login.ts file.

**Login HTML**

```
<label class="ci-ter-head ci-opc-50">Email address</label>                          
</div>
<div class="wrapper ci-pl-30 ci-pr-30 ci-pt-5">
   <ion-input autofocus="true" type="text" id="loginField" class="animated ci-form-field ci-font-size-12 ci-text-clr3 ci-back-input-colr ci-back-input-border-colr ci-mb-10 ci-email-height" [(ngModel)]="userSignInInfo.email" required></ion-input>
</div>
<div class="wrapper ci-pl-30 ci-mt-20">                          
   <label class="ci-ter-head ci-opc-50">Password</label>
</div>
<div class="wrapper ci-pl-30 ci-pr-30 " style="position:relative;">
<ion-input type="{{feildType}}" clearOnEdit="false" id="passwordField" class="animated ci-form-field ci-font-size-12 ci-text-clr3 ci-back-input-colr ci-back-input-border-colr ci-mb-10 ci-password-height" [(ngModel)]="userSignInInfo.password" required>
<span *ngIf="!platform.is('ios')" [hidden] = "shPassword" (click)="showPassword($event);"><img src="../../assets/images/show.svg"></span>
<span *ngIf="!platform.is('ios')" [hidden] = "!shPassword" (click)="showPassword($event);"><img src="../../assets/images/hide.svg"></span>
</ion-input>
```

**Signup HTML**

```
<ion-col size-xs="12" size-md="6" class="ci-pr-20">
   <label class="ci-ter-head ci-opc-50 ci-required">Email Address</label>
   <ion-input autofocus="true" type="email" class="inputField" (ionChange)="emailKeydown($event, 'signUpForm')"  [ngClass]="{'close-icon': validationVaribles.errorIconEmail, 'right-icon' : validationVaribles.successIconEmail }" [(ngModel)]="userSignUpInfo.email" class="ci-form-field ci-sec-head"></ion-input>
</ion-col>
<ion-col size-xs="12" size-md="6" class="ci-pr-20">
   <label class="ci-ter-head ci-opc-50 ci-required">Screen Name</label>
   <ion-input type="text" class="inputField" (ionChange)="userKeydown($event)" [ngClass]="{'close-icon': validationVaribles.errorIconUser, 'right-icon' : validationVaribles.successIconUser }" [(ngModel)]="userSignUpInfo.screenName" class="ci-form-field ci-sec-head"></ion-input>
</ion-col>
```

Comment: Right now autofocus="true" is works only for Login screen not working on Signup and other screens of same component.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

"No more than one element in the document may have the autofocus attribute. If put on more than one element, the first one with the attribute receives focus."

So you may try to bind a variable to your autofocus attribute and set it dynamically, something like this:

```
Input 1:
<ion-input [autofocus]="inputOneAutofocusEnabled">

Input 2:
<ion-input [autofocus]="inputTwoAutofocusEnabled">
```

and set inputOneAutofocusEnabled / inputOneAutofocusEnabled = true / false in your ts file.

Comment: Please share some more code here https://codepen.io/ or somewhere similar.

Comment: @shirishlakhe Please add more details to your problem. You said "its not working", what exactly is not working? You need to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us reproduce the problem

Comment: I am adding more code please check this one. I want to use mutiple autofocus on different screens of same component.